# In Django, how do I clear a sessionkey?

Tags: python, django, session

I set a session like this:

```
request.session['mykey']= 33
```

How do I clear it? I just want to DELETE it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
 del request.session['mykey']
```

Comment: May need to also do `request.session.modified = True`

Comment: Here's the specific Django document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.__delitem__